# Crontab generating RVM error on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, rvm, cron, ubuntu-14.04

When running a cron job that states

```
/home/user/.rvm/bin/rvm 1.9.3-p550 do bundle exec rake ts:rebuild RAILS_ENV=
```

Ubuntu 14.04 sends a mail with the following message

```
RVM is not a function, selecting rubies with 'rvm use ...' will not work.
```

The ./profile includes the following line:

```
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin" # Add RVM
```

what is the fix?

Answer (score 0):

`source ~/.profile ;` before your command.

Comment: `/bin/sh: 1: /home/this_user/.profile: Permission denied`  I suppose crontab is running under root  and the RVM function is one under this_user's prvileges...  so how do we fool root into using this_user's profile?

Comment: `su this_user` is a way, but you'd better use users' crontab instead of root crontab. Then you might not need to use source.

Comment: thoroughly confused now! if I `sudo crontab -e` I get a blank file. Thus what I'm editing as this_user is the user's cron tab.  Which throws the Permission denied error in a WAT basket...